# Set Interface Java

Tags: java, collections

The below functions returns the frequency of numbers in an array using HashMap. In this function there is a line:-

```
Set<Integer> set= map.keySet();
```

How the above line works. I know Set is an interface and there are many implementing classes like HashSet,TreeSet etc. But what `map.keySet()` returns to `set` variable ? Also when we write `Set<Integer> set= new HashSet();` how the set variable can be used to access `HashSet` as `set` is an interface variable ?

```
public static int[] GetFrequency(int [] array){

HashMap<Integer ,Integer > map = new HashMap<Integer,Integer>();      

for(int i =0;i<array.length;i++){

if(map.get(array[i])==null) map.put(array[i],1);
else{
int k = map.get(array[i]);
map.put(array[i],k+1);
}

}

int a[] = new int[map.size()];

Set<Integer> set= map.keySet();

int i =0;
for(int s : set)
a[i++]=map.get(s);
return a;

}
```

Comment: Heard of something called Polymorphism? Google it!

Comment: It's called Polymorphism.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Set set= map.keySet();
>
> How the above line works.

Simply because `HashMap.keySet()` returns an impmenentation of `AbstractSet` (internal), which implements  `Set`

> Also when we write Set set= new HashSet(); how the set
>   variable can be used to access HashSet as set is an interface variable
>   ?

`Set` interface defines a contract, and `HashSet` being **implementer** *adheres to the contract* (implements all the methods). In this way `Set` is a **super type** of `HashSet`, so `HashSet` can be assigned to `Set`

If we say `Set<String> set = new HashSet<String>();`, with `set` only those methods will be accessed which is defined in `Set` contract (interface). Mostly people prefer defining the reference of super type (i,e `Set`) because, tomorrow if the implementation changes no code change is required on other parts of the code

For example:

```
//implementation can change
Set<String> set = new HashSet<String>();
//set = new TreeSet<String>();
//set = new LinkedHashSet<String>();

//this part will not be impacted
set.add("abc");
```

Comment: `HashMap.keySet()` does not return a `HashSet` but a [custom implementation](http://www.grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/7-b147/java/util/HashMap.java#HashMap.KeySet) of a `Set` that uses the internal values of the `HashMap` directly instead of creating a copy. It's a "view" of the internal data.

Answer (score 0):

Understand the relation like that:

Suppose you have a 4 Boxes, the first is square, second is rectangle, and third&forth are another shape, but at the end, they all are Boxes.

So, the box is the base, but each of the forth boxes has it's special shape.

So, what I am gonna tell is, `HashSet` is a `Set` but have its own behavior also.